# Logarithm, LUT and how to make it non-linear

Tags: logarithms

Currently I calculate log as following:

```
#define MAXLOG 1001
double myloglut[MAXLOG];
void MyLogCreate()
{
    int i;
    double exp, expinc;
    expinc = (2.0 - 0.1) / MAXLOG;
    for (i = 0, exp = 0.1; i <= MAXLOG; ++i, exp += expinc)
            myloglut[i] = log(exp);
    myloglut[478] = 0; // this one need to be precise
}

double MyLog(double v)
{
    int idx = (int)((MAXLOG*(v - 0.1)) / (2.0 - 0.1));
    return myloglut[idx];
}
```

As you can see I'm interested only in range `0.1 - 2.0`. However, I need more precision around `0`. How can I achieve that non linear calculation? Also is there any way to use some interpolation in this function for better precision?

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve by writing these routines?

Comment: It's been used in Rhumb geo distance calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log(m \cdot 2^e) = \log m + e \log 2$$